# Adding link to button only

Tags: html, css, visual-studio, frontend, bootstrap-5

I am using bootstrap 5 to create a website. On one of my pages the header is an image and the image has text and a button over it. When someone clicks the button they are supposed to be taken to another site but right now if someone clicks the button or any where on the the image they are taken to the site.

```css
body {
  background: hsl(233, 47%, 96%);
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

#copyright {
  border-top: 1px solid hsl(0, 0%, 20%);
}

.c-item {
  height: 900px;
}

.c-img {
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  filter: brightness(0.6);
}

#team-img {
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
  background-color: hsl(196, 66%, 82%);
}

.dropdown-item:hover {
  background-color: hsl(198, 100%, 43%);
}
















#button {
    background-color:hsl(208, 96%, 29%);
    border: 1px solid hsl(208, 96%, 29%);
}

#button:hover {
    background-color:hsl(198, 100%, 43%);
    border: 1px solid hsl(198, 100%, 43%);
}

#caption-h2 {
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 10px hsl(0, 0%, 0%);
    padding:1rem;
}

#caption-p {
    color: hsl(208, 96%, 29%);
}
```

```html
<!-- SHOWCASE START -->
<section>
    <div id="herocarousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel" >
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active c-item">
              <img src="./images/about001.jpg" class="d-block w-100 c-img" alt="...">
              <div class="carousel-caption mt-3 top-0 ">
                <!-- <p class="mt-5 text-uppercase text-start">Contact Us</p> -->
                <p class=" dtext-uppercase text-center" id="caption-p">We&nbsp;Are</p>
                <h2 class="display-3 fw-bolder text-capitalize" id="caption-h2">Project Name</h2>
                <div>
                    <a href="link">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary px-4 py-2 fs-5 mb-5" id="button">Book&nbsp;a&nbsp;Call</button>
                    </a>
                    
                </div>      
            </div>  
        </div> 
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- SHOWCASE CLOSE -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [button tags](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/buttons/#button-tags): remove the button, and style link as button (also, add the URL to href attribute, and you can add `target="_blank"` so that it opens in a new window):

```
<a href="link-to-somewhere" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary px-4 py-2 fs-5 mb-5" id="button">Book&nbsp;a&nbsp;Call</a>
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>


<section>
  <div id="herocarousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active c-item">
        <img src="https://placehold.co/600x400" class="d-block w-100 c-img" alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-caption mt-3 top-0 ">
          <!-- <p class="mt-5 text-uppercase text-start">Contact Us</p> -->
          <p class=" dtext-uppercase text-center" id="caption-p">We&nbsp;Are</p>
          <h2 class="display-3 fw-bolder text-capitalize" id="caption-h2">Project Name</h2>
          <div>

            <a href="link-to-somewhere" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary px-4 py-2 fs-5 mb-5" id="button">Book&nbsp;a&nbsp;Call</a>


          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: when i copy your code directly into mine it still doesn't work so this makes me think its a styling issue but I am not sure what it could be do you have any idea and I also added CSS to my original question

Comment: i found the problem i was putting the link on the wrong button